# Going through model's each layer individually gives other result than using forward

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to tinker with some intermediate layer result from a pretrained resnet. I noticed a drop in accuracy when just iterating over the layers of a specific block. Upon further inspection I saw that the intermediate results change if i iterate or use the builtin forward function.

```py
net = resnet18()
before = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(net.children())[:7])
middle = list(net.children())[7]
```

`middle` is a basic block that looks like that:

```
Sequential(
  (0): BasicBlock(
    (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (downsample): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (1): BasicBlock(
    (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  )
)
```

What i am trying to do is get the intermediate result from the second `BasicBlock['conv1']`. Here's what i wrote:

```py
x = self.before(x)
bb1 = list(self.middle.children())[0]
x = bb1(x)
bb2 = list(self.middle.children())[1]

print(bb2(x))
for i, layer in enumerate(bb2.children()):
    x = layer(x)
    if i == 0:
        z = copy.copy(x)

print(x)
```

For the first print statement i get:

```
tensor([[[[1.1271e-01, 1.1205e-01],
          [1.6054e-01, 1.4965e-01]],...)
```

For the second print statement i get:

```
tensor([[[[ 0.0533,  0.0498],
          [ 0.0607,  0.0574]],...)
```

In my understanding they should be exactly the same. what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to tinker with intermediate results while preserving accuracy, you could set the network to evaluation mode using net.eval() before iterating through layers or manipulating intermediate outputs. This ensures that BatchNormalization layers use their learned statistics and Dropout layers do not apply dropout during the forward pass.

Modify your code

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models as models

net = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
net.eval()  # Set the network to evaluation mode

before = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(net.children())[:7])
middle = list(net.children())[7]
```

Comment: but when i do `bb2(x)` i also do not set it to eval() so why when i iterate it changes